# Объясните что это за конструкция?

Tags: css

Сорри конечно, может и нубский вопрос, но объясните что это за конструкция?

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
*+p {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

И в каких браузерах это будет работать?

Answer (score 2):

Первый - стиль применяется ко всем абзацам. 
Второй - ко всем элементам, для которых абзац является соседним элементом. 
По поводу поддержки тут:

http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/adjacent

Comment: То есть, в данном случае margin-top: 15px; будет применен только к верхнему p? http://ssmaker.ru/b0e00c1b.png

Comment: Ответ неверный. Данная конструкция сработает не для всех элементов, для которых абзац является соседним элементом, а для самого абзаца, если перед ним стоит какой-либо элемент.

Comment: Спасибо за правильную формулировку. mJeevas правильно отметил всё